# Is there a way to sum the rows above the current row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to replicate a spreadsheet into a database and I am stumped on how to only sum the rows above the current row like I can do in excel. For example, the formula for the one column is as follows:

```
=SUM($B$9:$B9)/SUM($E$9:$E9)
=SUM($B$9:$B10)/SUM($E$9:$E10)
=SUM($B$9:$B11)/SUM($E$9:$E11)
```

.... and so on.

I need to somehow reproduce this formula in my select qry but not sure how?

```
SELECT Column1,Column2, SUM(Column1) + SUM(Column2) as Expr1
From tblTest
Group By Column1,Column2
```

Any ideas?

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3  Total     Col1/Total      Trying to get this               
    7       0       3     10         70.00%          70.00%
    1       0       1                100.00%         72.73%
    2       0       4     6          33.33%          58.82%
    3       1       1     5          60.00%          59.09%
```

Comment: What you're looking for is a `running total`.  Try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290136.

Comment: Can you show an example of expected output to clarify?

Comment: A search here on `[sql][ms-access] running total` turned up [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8904750/62576) as the first result.

Comment: Say for example column1 has values 1-4 (4 rows) then Column 2 has values 1-4 (4 rows). Then in column3 for each row 1-4 it will add every row above it (so row 2 column 3 would sum column1 rows 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

The trick is you want to use a subquery with a way to identify all the previous rows.

```
SELECT  ID, 
        (
            SELECT SUM(ValueColumn)
            FROM    Test T2
            WHERE T2.ID <= T1.ID
        ) RunningSum
FROM
        Test T1
ORDER BY
        T1.ID
```

This will work.  If you have a large data set you may want to just select the data and calculate in your application as you'll be able to keep a running-sum as you loop through the data more efficiently than this query will run.

Comment: This is my qry and I am getting error near select statement? SELECT ID, DateColumn, Contamination, BrokenGlass, OtherReasons, SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons) AS Total, SUM(Contamination) / Total AS Expr1, (SELECT SUM(Contamination) FROM tblTest T2 WHERE WHERE T2.ID <= T2.ID) RunningSum FROM tblTest GROUP BY ID, DateColumn, Contamination, BrokenGlass, OtherReasons

Comment: @user1342164 i think you want `SELECT ID, DateColumn, Contamination, BrokenGlass, OtherReasons, 
SUM(Contamination) + SUM(BrokenGlass) + SUM(OtherReasons) AS Total, 
SUM(Contamination) / Total AS Expr1, 
(SELECT SUM(Contamination) FROM tblTest T2  WHERE T2.ID <= T2.ID) As RunningSum 
FROM tblTest GROUP BY ID, DateColumn, Contamination, BrokenGlass, OtherReasons`